# "line 36: cd: HOME not set" in start.sh running Boot2Docker installed using Docker for Windows Installer v1.6.0

Tags: windows, installation, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I have installed Docker on my Windows laptop using Docker for Windows Installer v1.6.0. When I ran the start.sh script for the first time, it initializes and starts the VM, but then the script gives the error "line 36: cd: HOME not set" and exits:

```
C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>start.sh

initializing...

starting...
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
............................oooooooo
Started.
Writing C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem

To connect the Docker client to the Docker daemon, please set:
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH='C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm'
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376


IP address of docker VM:
192.168.59.103

setting environment variables ...
Writing C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\ca.pem
Writing C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\cert.pem
Writing C:\Users\Administrator\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm\key.pem
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH='C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.boot2docker\\certs\\boot2docker-vm'
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

You can now use `docker` directly, or `boot2docker ssh` to log into the VM.
C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows\start.sh: line 36: cd: HOME not set

C:\Program Files\Boot2Docker for Windows>
```

Lines 36 and 37 of the script are:

```
cd
exec "$BASH" --login -i
```

I've had to make some changes to the install to get this far:

- When `start.sh` opened WordPad, I made `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe` Windows' default program for `.sh` files
- When `start.sh` encountered the error "line 5: clear: command not found", I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` to my system's path
- When the VM failed to start with "error in run: Failed to start machine "boot2docker-vm": exit status 1", I ran `boot2docker delete` and `boot2docker download` to delete the VM and download the ISO again

Now I'm stuck on the error "line 36: cd: HOME not set" in `start.sh`.

Docker's Windows Installer v1.6.0 was just published yesterday (April 16), so there's not much help on it yet (such as a GitHub or Docker's forums).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issues. The one with HOME was resolved by adding the following line in empty one at #35:

```
export HOME=$HOMEPATH
```

Comment: I had docker on drive D, while home folder in C:\Users\<user folder> and $HOME gave me \Users\<user folder> which terminated the shell script with error again.
So I just commented out the cd instruction thus starting bash console in current folder instead.

Comment: Agree with you but still potentially some scripts may need HOME variable and it will be easy for you to just type "cd" while working... If you have docker on drive D: you may then "cd" to it and also you'll have environment variable HOME set.

Answer (score 0):

The two lines in question are restarting Bash, presumably so that modifications to dotfiles take effect.

Try commenting out those two lines. After running `start.sh`, exit and restart Bash yourself. Finally, run

```
eval "$(boot2docker.exe shellinit 2>/dev/null | sed  's,\\,\\\\,g')"
```

in the new shell to make sure the environment is set up. For all future sessions, that `eval` command should be all you need to configure the shell for Docker.

Answer (score 0):

First of all for all others as reference: there is an issue open at Github in which this problem is being discussed. See this: https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/issues/102

Bobby opened this issue and there are a few hints how to possibly fix this.

One of them is a solution I discovered for myself (I ran into the same problem):
I had TortoiseGit (coupled with msysgit 1.9.5) installed prior to installing Boot2Docker. In the msysgit installation while installing TortoiseGit, I may not have checked the "associate .sh files with git bash".

I then manually reinstalled msysgit from https://msysgit.github.io/ and choose to "associate .sh files with git bash". After this, Boot2Docker worked and the "HOME not set" seems fixed.

At least this solution worked for me so it's worth giving it a try if you also have TortoiseGit installed.